# Excel PowerQuery: how do I add an IsNotNull column

Tags: powerquery

I have a simple function that I'd like to run on the values in a column, resulting in another column.

```
    let 
        ThisIsNotNull = (input) => if (input = null) then false else true,
        Source = ...
```

eventually there is a text column with Nulls in it, let's call it TextColumn.
I'd like to add another column alongside it with a value of **=ThisIsNotNull(TextColumn).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add column... Custom column with formula

```
 = ThisIsNotNull([NameOfColumnToTest])
```

But really you can skip the function and just use

```
 = if [NameOfColumnToTest] = null then false else true
```